# get page number which contains particular word in pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How to get page number which contains particular word in pdf  in pdfbox API in java?

I am able to read word with:

```
PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
String contents = s.getText(pdoc);  
if(contents.contains("SUBSCRIPTION DETAILS")){
...
}
```

But not able to find page number which contains this word

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PDFTextStripper` allows you to read exact page. So you need to iterate through all pages and check if the page contains certain string:

```
PDDocument pdoc = ...;
for(int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < pdoc.getPageCount(); i++){

    PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
    s.setStartPage(pageNumber);
    s.setEndPage(pageNumber);
    String pageText = reader.getText(pdoc);
    String contents = s.getText(pdoc);  
    if(contents.contains("SUBSCRIPTION DETAILS")){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i want page number which contains that text. Please let me know if my question is clear to you.

Comment: You have to iterate through the pages and check every page. See code.

Comment: Could you please let me know how can i found the font of the same text in same page in pdf. Thanks In Advance

Comment: In your code, the initial value of pageNumber must be 1, not 0, as start/end pages are 1-based.